# Why should I put SEEK_SET twice

Tags: c

I want to modify some vowels of a file by "5". The following code works. However, I do not understand why I should put fseek twice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void print_file_contents(const char *filename) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    char letter;

    if((fp=fopen(filename,"r+"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    int size=ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        fseek(fp,i,SEEK_SET);
        letter=fgetc(fp);
    
        if((letter=='a') || (letter=='e') || (letter=='i'))
        {
            fseek(fp,i,SEEK_SET); // WHY THIS FSEEK ?
            fwrite("5",1,sizeof(char),fp);
        }

    }

    fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print_file_contents("myfile");
    return 0;
}
```

In my opinion, the first `fseek(fp, i, SEEK_SET)` is used to set the file position indicator to the current character being processed, so that the character can be read using `fgetc`. Hence, the cursor is updated every time so there is no need to add another `fseek(fp, i, SEEK_SET);`.

Comment: Note that `fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END); int size=ftell(fp); rewind(fp);` is a *really* bad way to get the size of a file.  Use `GetFileSize()` on Windows, or `stat()` on POSIX systems. There are all kinds of problems with `fseek()`/`ftell()` - not least of which are problems with files larger than 2 GB, and text files in Windows...

Comment: @void_brain, `for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  {  fseek(fp,i,SEEK_SET);` risks UB.  `fseek(fp,i,SEEK_SET)` OK for binary files,  For text files, `fseek()` has limitations.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica *`fseek(fp,i,SEEK_SET)` OK for binary files, ...*  Mostly true, because Windows and POSIX both extend C so that it works.  [Formally, though](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268): "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, **has undefined behavior for a binary stream**..."

Comment: Agree.  To handle many issues, best to use [@zwol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75286051/2410359), but with an `ftell()/fseek()` approach.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Answer added to illustrate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fgetc` advanced the file position; if you want to replace the character you just read, you need to rewind back to the same position you were in when you read the character to replace.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the C standard mandates a seek-like operation when you switch between reading and writing (and between writing and reading).

> [§7.21.5.s The `fopen` function ¶7](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7):
>
> ¶7 When a file is opened with update mode ('`+`' as the second or third character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end- of-file.

Also, calling `fgetc()` moves the file position forward one character; if the write worked (it's undefined behaviour if you omit the seek-like operation), you'd overwrite the next character, not the one you just read.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct: *two* of the three `fseek` calls in this program are unnecessary.

The necessary `fseek` is the one inside the `if((letter=='a') || (letter=='e') || (letter=='i'))` conditional.  That one is needed to back up the file position so you overwrite the character you just read (i.e. the vowel), not the character *after* the vowel.

The `fseek` inside the loop (but outside the `if`) is unnecessary because both `fgetc` and `fwrite` advance the file position, so it will always set the file position to the position it already has.  And the `fseek` before the loop is unnecessary because you do not need to know how big the file is to implement this algorithm.

This code can be tightened up considerably.  I'd write it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void replace_aie_with_5_in_place(const char *filename) 
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r+");  // (1)
 
    if (!fp) {
        perror(filename);  // (2)
        exit(1);
    }

    int letter;
    while ((letter = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {  // (3)
        if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i') { // (4)
            fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR); // (5)
            fputc('5', fp);
            if (fflush(fp)) { // (6)
                perror(filename);
                exit(1);
            }
    }

    if (fclose(fp)) {  // (7)
        perror(filename);
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    replace_aei_with_5_in_place(argv[1]); // (8)
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

1. It is often (but not always) better to write operations with side effects, like `fopen`, separately from conditionals checking whether they succeeded.
2. When a system-level operation fails, **always** print both the name of any file involved, and the decoded value of `errno`.  `perror(filename)` is a convenient way to do this.
3. You don't need to know the size of the file you're crunching because you can use a loop like this, instead.  Also, this is an example of an exception to (1).
4. Why not `'o'` and `'u'` also?
5. Here's the necessary call to fseek, and the *other* reason you don't need to know the size of the file: you can use `SEEK_CUR` to back up by one character.
6. This `fflush` is necessary because we're switching from writing to reading, as stated in Jonathan Leffler's answer.  Inconveniently, it also consumes the notification for some (but not all) I/O errors, so you have to check whether it failed.
7. Because you are writing to the file, you must also check for *delayed* I/O errors, reported only on `fclose`.  (This is a design error in the operating system, but one that we are permanently stuck with.)
8. Best practice is to pass the name of the file to munge on the command line, not to hardcode it into the program.

Comment: You need two seek-like operations — you need another after the `fputc()` and before the next `fgetc()`.  See the section of the standard I quoted in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75285996/15168).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I forgot that rule. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

[@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) well states why code used multiple `fseek()`: To cope with changing between reading and writing.

---

`int size=ftell(fp);` is weak as the range of returned values from `ftell()` is `long`.

---

Seeking in a text file (as OP has) also risks **undefined behavior** (UB).

> For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be `SEEK_SET`.  C17dr § 7.21.9.1 3.

Better to use [@zwol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388520/zwol) like approach with a small change.

Do not assume a smooth linear mapping.  Instead, note the location and then return to it as needed.

```
int replacement = '5';
for (;;) {
    long position = ftell(fp);
    if (ftell == -1) {
        perror(filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    int letter = fgetc(fp);
    if (letter == EOF) {
        break;
    }
    if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i') {
        fseek(fp, position, SEEK_SET);
        fputc(replacement, fp);
        if (fflush(fp)) {
            perror(filename);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Research `fgetpos(), fsetpos()` for an even better solution that handles all file sizes, even ones longer than `LONG_MAX`.